# How can I calculate difference between two dates?

Tags: c#

How can I calculate the number of days between two dates in C#?

I'm using following code to to generate the days.

```
private void Days()
    {
        lbl_borroweddate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        lbl_duedate.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays(14).ToShortDateString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, that should be easy

```
private void Days()
{
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(14);
    lbl_borroweddate.Text = dt1.ToShortDateString();
    lbl_duedate.Text = dt2.ToShortDateString();
    TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;
    double days = (ts).TotalDays;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you subtract dates you get a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var borrow = DateTime.Today;
var due = DateTime.Today.AddDays(14);

TimeSpan diff = due - borrow;
Console.WriteLine(diff.TotalDays);
```

This has properties such as `TotalDays` for getting the number of days between 2 dates.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime +/- operator overload returns a "TimeSpan" that will give you ."TotalDays" property and others you can also need. Like Below :

```
            (DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now).TotalDays
```